# VBA - Error 2042

Tags: vba, excel

The problem I am trying to solve is a partitioning problem, where I have to split n weights into k groups, with the weight of each group as evenly as possible.

I am trying to apply some form of heuristics into my initial solution, to try to improve on a random start but keep coming across an error.

The basics of my initial solution algorithm is; select next largest unsorted element and place it into the group that has the least weight in it. Note: I have presorted my elements into size order.

I have started with the following code;

```
Sub initialsolution(s() As Integer, n As Integer, k As Integer, w() As Long)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, l As long
    ReDim mass(1 To k) As Long

    For i = 1 To n
        j = WorksheetFunction.Min(mass)
        l = Application.Match(j, mass)
        mass(l) = mass(l) + w(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Where s() is currently an empty array from 1 to n, which I will populate later, n is the number of weights, k is the number of groups, and w() is the sorted array of the weights, in my trial case, n = 8, k = 3, w = (5,4,3,3,2,2,1,1).

My issue arises when i = 6 and I am considering the weight 2. Mass has values of (6,6,5), therefore the min value in mass, j, is 5. However in the next line, setting a value for l an error is formed. When I change l to be a variant it sets its value to be Error 2042, when it should be 3. This causes the error code "Run-time Error '13': Type mismatch" Due to Error 2042 being unable to be used as an index.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You've written a lot about the background and then don't seem to have actually posted the line of code causing the error... VBA errors tend to be relatively generic, so it's useful to have a [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try editing your question to make it easier to answer on the specific error.

Comment: How are you passing your arguments?

Comment: This is the line of code within my larger piece that runs the sub 
"initialsolution s, n, k, w" Where all of the parameters are already predefined

Comment: Mass is empty, and you're trying to match j against it. It will be breaking on that line.

Comment: Mass isn't "empty" the values within it are 0 by default. The algorithm would only break towards the end of the run through, when i = 6. I have since found a solution, see below. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. If I use

```
l = Application.Match(j, mass, 0)
```

Instead of

```
l = Application.Match(j, mass)
```

It works. I'm not sure what the previous bug was however this new method only considers the first time it comes across the match value and returns this index.